# Is {...{ key }} the same as key={key} to assign a react property?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I'm beginner developer in React and few days ago I saw and interesting syntax that I don't understand.

On the View component there is {...{key}},
I would write instead key={key}, is it exactly the same? and do you have a link or an explanation?

```
  render() {
    const { tasks } = this.props;
    return (
        <View>
          {
            tasks.map((task, key) => {
              return (
                <View {...{ key }}>
                  <Task/>
                </View>
              );
            })
          }
        </View>
    );
  }
```

Comment: It is the same. Beware, that the property name will be key, whereas if you were to use `={}` syntax, then you can name the property specifically.

Comment: Yes, it's the same. Not sure why people would prefer that syntax.

Comment: @Chris i use it to write many properties out that i dont want to modify the name of.

Comment: In case you want to read more about spread syntax - https://oprea.rocks/blog/what-do-the-three-dots-mean-in-javascript/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think of the properties you supply to `<View>` as an object to props. Lets say

```
var variable = 2
```

Writing `<View value={variable}>`, in essence, is like writing:

```
// value={variable} is the same as {value: variable}

props = {
  value: 2
}
```

However, writing `<View {...{variable}}>` makes it less efficient to declare the property name, it will always be the same as the variable name unless specified:

```
// {...{variable}} spreads out into {variable: variable}

props: {
  variable: 2
}

// {...{value: variable}} spreads out into {value: variable}
// which is a slower way of writing value={variable}
```

One of the only real use cases of the second syntax is to quickly pass multiple variables that you wish to keep the same name:

```
<View {...{ user, firstName, lastName, email }}>
// rather than
<View user={user} firstName={firstName} lastName={lastName} email={email}>
```

A major downside to this syntax, however, is that you *cannot* edit the variable itself, without having to declare the property name. For instance you can write this with the first syntax:

```
value={variable + 2}
```

but you cannot write:

```
{...{variable + 2}}
```

Where is the property name? You would have to write:

```
{...{value: value + 2}}
```

Which, again, is a **slower** way of writing the first syntax.

---

A slightly different use case of the spread syntax is to pass down multiple object properties at once. For example, say we have this object:

```
var user = {
  firstName: 'foo',
  lastName: 'bar',
  email: 'foo@bar.com',
}
```

Instead of writing:

```
<View firstName={user.firstName} lastName={user.lastName} email={user.email}>
```

We can simply write:

```
<View {...user}>
```

---

**TL;DR**
Overall, for writing long lists of variables that you just want to pass down to the next component, use the spread syntax (`{...{variable1, variable2}}`), otherwise, use the regular syntax (`value={variable}`), as you'll have much more control as to what you pass down to your components.

Comment: You'd have a very valid point if we were talking about a regular prop. However, `key` is a special prop as it doesn't get "passed down" and it helps React identifying items in a list - hence it *cannot* have any name other than `key` without also changing the result.

Comment: That's very very true, that completely passed over my head, ill change that now

Comment: Another major downside to this syntax is that, for every loop will create a new object which is unnecessarily

Comment: @Isaac Turns out it is 33% slower to do it that way. Interesting.

Comment: @Chris interesting, how do get this statistics ?

Comment: @adesurirey I made a test on jsperf.com

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's the same.

Normally, you would see a mapping written like this:

```
tasks.map((task, index) =>
```

but by instead writing:

```
tasks.map((task, key) =>
```

you can assign a key to the item by just `{...{key}}` instead of writing `key={index}`

---

It comes down to a matter of preference, really. However, I personally think this is just unnecessary "over-engineering" of something very basic.

Answer (score 0):

```js
<View {...{ key }}>
  <Task/>
</View>
```

The code above is in fact consisting multiple parts

1. create an object on the fly, with whatever value you get for `key` while looping, assign it to a property of this newly created object, with the property name "key"
2. Spread out the object that created from step 1 and being used as property of View

Hence it's much better to write below instead

```js
<View key={key}>
...
</View>
```

Comment: I checked with https://infoheap.com/online-react-jsx-to-javascript/ and seems it transpile to same code as default format. So no extra on-fly objects will be created for 'React.createElement'